# Fancybox v3 Beta 1 (disable title)

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, title

difference betwin images/titles

[image]

I setup my gallery, but when I go next or prew picture, in the first time load picture and then title. After scrolling picture title area moves it. I want to disable title area. But I can't it.

This code do not work:

```
helpers: { 
    title: null
}
```

and

```
helpers: {
    title: false
}
```

When I disable title using CSS, I do not see text, but area of title remains.
test site: http://eurospichki.esy.es/ (first page)

Comment: maybe some code how your facybox is build

Comment: maybe you are not applying the option to the right selector http://jsfiddle.net/b9Ts8/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If Javascript parameter is not working then you can achieve it via CSS also:

```
.fancybox-title-outside-wrap {
  display:none !important;
}
```

Although, this is not perfect solution but it will hide your title at least.

Comment: I try it. Realy this method is hide title, but not area of title. For first time I delete "title" tag in HTML. But for future I need complectly hide area of this field. Thank's!